# show hide divs under foreach

Tags: html, foreach

I have this code :

```
{foreach from=$aProfiles item=aModules}
{foreach from=$aModules key=sPrivacy item=aProfile}
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table_left">{$aProfile.phrase}</div>
        <div class="table_right">contents ...........</div>         
    </div>
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

This will generate many divs for `div class="table"` that content div `class="table_left"` and 
`div class="table_right"` .....

**What I want is :**
`div class="table_right"` to be hidden `(disply:none)` ,
click on `div class="table"` will show it . Then if click on another `div class="table"` will hide the opening div and show `class="table_right"` were clicked .

i succes to do this but was showing the first one of all the divs group .
to understand what i mean exactly please see the facebook account sitings , wen click on name show the 
name informations then if click on username hide name's informations and show username informations .

Sorry if my english is poor.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to get it ...

1. Create a .hidden class with style display: none;
2. then use jquery click function to add remove class ..
3. in loop add hidden class with table_right

```
.hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

```
<script>

$(function(){

 $(".table").click(function(){
    $('.table_right').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).children('.table_right').removeClass('hidden');
 });

});

</script>
```

and the forech like below ...

```
{foreach from=$aProfiles item=aModules}
{foreach from=$aModules key=sPrivacy item=aProfile}
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table_left">{$aProfile.phrase}</div>
        <div class="table_right hidden">contents ...........</div>         
    </div>
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: i have this code work just on the first div .
this mean if i click on any div in the divs under the foreach
it will show just the first div on top :

Comment: {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
        {/literal}
        
        {foreach from=$aProfiles item=aModules}
{foreach from=$aModules key=sPrivacy item=aProfile} 
  <div class="table" onclick="showStuff('rightmeshow');">
   <div class="table_left">
    {$aProfile.phrase}
   </div>
   <div id="rightmeshow" class="table_right hidden">
    
                contents ..........   
   </div>   
  </div>
        {/foreach}
{/foreach}

Comment: can you please improve it to work on all the divs please ??!
thank you

Comment: i dont want togly 
i just want that evry div show his table_right div and hide the opening one onclick .